# addArrangedSubview vs addSubview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

I'm newbie and I've wrote a customView inherited from `StackView` and I created a `button` programmatically with few attributes and when I add it to my custom view, I have two problems:

1. If I use `addArrangedSubview(myBtn)`, my view ignores attributes that
   I added and fills the whole width. But if I use `addSubView(myBtn)`,
   It's ok(a blue square in 44x44)
2. If I use `addArrangedSubview(myBtn)`, `addTarget()` not works and
   `myBtn` is not clickable, but when I use `addSubView(myBtn)`, It works
   perfectly.

Here is my custom view class:

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIStackView {

//MARK: Initialization
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupButtons()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:coder)
    setupButtons()
}

//MARK: Private Methods
private func setupButtons() {

    // Create the button
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    // Add constraints
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

    // Setup the button action
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    // Add the button to the stack
    addArrangedSubview(button)

}
//MARK: Button Action
@objc func ratingButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Button pressed ")
}

}
```

Here is the preview:

[image]
[image]

What's difference between `addSubView()` and `addArrangedSubview()`? why these problems happens?

Comment: It is working properly. No issue with `addArrangedSubview`

Comment: I added images to my question. check it out

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you want to add several buttons horizontally (such as with a typical "stars" rating control).

A `UIStackView`, as might be guessed from its `.addArrangedSubview()` method, ***arranges*** its subviews, based on its `.axis`, `.alignment`, `.distribution` and `.spacing` properties, as well as its `frame`.

So, do some reading about `UIStackView` and how it can be used. Most likely, you are currently constraining your custom view with:

- top
- leading
- trailing (or width)

So adding your button as an `arrangedSubView` results in it stretching to the width of the stack view, because that's the default.

Adding it as a `subview` simply overlays the button on the stack view, instead of allowing the stack view to arrange it, and your stack view likely then has a height of zero -- so the button cannot be tapped.

Try setting *only* top and leading constraints when you add your custom stack view. That should give you a `44 x 44` button that can be tapped.

As you add more buttons using `.addArrangedSubview()`, those buttons will be arranged horizontally, which is probably what you want.

Comment: thanks @DonMag. check my images that I added to my question recently. in situation I use addView(), it is visible (does not has zero height as you said) but no responds to tap. I'm practicing [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) and it uses addArrangedSubView but result is different with mine!

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi - are you laying out your custom RatingControl in Storyboard or via code?

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi - oh, you're following the Food Tracker tutorial. Notice at the start of Part 4 - *"Implement a Custom Control"* - your vertical stack view is set to `Alignment: Leading`... during Part 4 you're instructed to change that to `Center`. At that point, your custom control should only be the width of the number of "star" buttons + the spacing, and should be centered below the image. If you had the vertical stack view set to `Alignment: Fill`, that is why your button stretched horizontally instead of using your defined width of `44`.

Comment: You're missing a point. Your custom *horizontal* stackView is embedded in a *vertical* stack view. Check the `Alignment` of the vertical stack view, and make sure ***it*** is set to `Center`. If you've added left and right constraints to your custom stack view, you have gone away from that tutorial.